# Retrieve JSON Data with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I have seen some other posts in Stackoverflow which were related. Tried that code but it did not work out for me.

I have a code that will get a data from database like this :

```
function getWrkNoTest($wrkno){

    $conf = new BBAgentConf();
    $log = new KLogger($conf->get_BBLogPath().$conf->get_BBDateLogFormat(),  $conf->get_BBLogPriority() );
    $connection = MySQLConnection();

    $getWrkNoTest ="";
    $lArrayIndex = 0;

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT a.jobinfoid, a.WRKNo, a.cate, a.det, a.compclosed, a.feedback, a.infoID, b.callerid, b.customername FROM
bb_jmsjobinfo a
LEFT JOIN bb_customer b ON a.customerid = b.customerid
WHERE a.WRKNo = '$wrkno';");

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $log->LogDebug("Query[".$query."]");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $getWrkNoTest = array("jobinfoid"=>$row['jobinfoid'],
                "WRKNo"=>$row['WRKNo'],
                "cate"=>$row['cate'],
                "det"=>$row['det'],
                "compclosed"=>$row['compclosed'],
                "feedback"=>$row['feedback'],
                "infoID"=>$row['customerid'],
                "customerid"=>$row['infoID'],
                "callerid"=>$row['callerid'],
            "customername"=>$row['customername']);

            $iList[$lArrayIndex] = $getWrkNoTest;
            $lArrayIndex = $lArrayIndex + 1;

        }
        $QueryResult = print_r($getWrkNoTest,true);
        $log->LogDebug("QueryResult[".$QueryResult."]");
        closeDB($connection);
        return $iList;

}
```

This code will connect to mysql ,database and retrieve data from database .Lets say this file name is mysql.php .After that I have a file named getjson.php ,this file will get the data from mysql.php and send to ajax .This file code is below :

```
<?php
//getCustomerNames will display all customer name that use the same number phone ,displayed on *top callername slection

include 'mysql.php'; 

        $wrkno = $_GET["wrkno"];

        $jms = getWrkNoTest($wrkno);

        foreach($jms as $findContact){
            $findContact['jobinfoid'];
            $findContact['WRKNo'] ;
            $findContact['cate'] ;
            $findContact['det'] ;
            $findContact['compclosed'] ;
            $findContact['feedback'] ;
            $findContact['customerid'] ;
            $findContact['infoID'];
            $findContact['infoID'];
            $findContact['customername'] ;
            $matches[] = $findContact;
        }
        echo json_encode($matches);
?>
```

Then ,this is my ajax code that will parse all data to html :

```
$.getJSON("jsonJms.php", {wrkno: wrkno}, function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key,val) {                               
                    $("#cname").val(val.customername);
                     $("#cnumb").val(val.callerid); 
                     $("#comp").val(val.compclosed);
                     $("#cate").val(val.cate);
                     $("#det").val(val.det);
                     $("#feed").val(val.feedback);


              });
            });
```

When this is run in the browser is just give a output Null . Please help me.Any help I will appreciate in whole my life.

Comment: If you look at the response form the server in firebug, what's actually coming back from jsonJms.php?

Comment: @Jiminyjetson It doesn't give any response from there

Comment: OK, so your GET request is returning an empty response? If you go directly to [your localhost url]/jsonJMS.php?workno=[a test value], does it still return nothing?

Comment: if there is no data coming in response.That means there is some problem in server side script.Please check net tab in firebug that will show you response.Please provide that response to further.

Comment: @Jiminyjetson yes,it just show a blank page

Comment: do you guys have any idea how can I get json data from my mysql.php into my getjson.php file .

Comment: So the problem is with your PHP rather than your JS. Put in some var_dumps and see what's happening at the various stages of the PHP function. Divide and conquer!

Answer (score 0):

Try below options,

Set the content type with `header('Content-type: application/json');` and then echo your data in jsonJms.php. [Check whether you getting the data in JSON data by hitting the URL directly in address bar with assigning wrkno variable].

Modify your code like below,

```
    $.getJSON("jsonJms.php", {wrkno: wrkno}, function(data) {                                            
                            $("#cname").val(data.customername);
                             $("#cnumb").val(data.callerid); 
                             $("#comp").val(data.compclosed);
                             $("#cate").val(data.cate);
                             $("#det").val(data.det);
                             $("#feed").val(data.feedback);

         })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Hope it will helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is coming back from the PHP layer, then that's where your problem is. 
Make sure your DB query is actually returning data, if so, check what's being done with it.